# A variable doesn't get assigned to function return

Tags: php, variables, methods, return-value, assign

Being new to programming, I am trying to sharpen my skills using the LeetCode problems. I started doing the *Longest Common Prefix* problem and came up to a problem where the $temp_var doesn't get assigned to a return value of reduceOneAndCheck method.

On the second iteration, the **reduceOneAndCheck **find the first common prefix and gets to return statement, but the **$temp_var** never gets assigned to that value.

So, my question is, if someone understands why it doesn't get assigned, why it happens? Where did it go wrong? Tried checking for any similar problem already, but didn't find anything, sorry if I missed some solution, being a newbie :)

`

```
class Solution {

    /**
     * @param String[] $strs
     * @return String
     */
    function longestCommonPrefix($strs) {
        $temp_var;
        
        foreach ($strs as $value) {
            if($temp_var === null || $temp_var === "") {
                $temp_var = $value; 
            }
            $temp_var = $this->reduceOneAndCheck($temp_var, $value); 
        }
        
        return $temp_var;
        
    }
    
    function reduceOneAndCheck(string &$temp_var, string $value) {
        if($temp_var == $value) {
            return $temp_var;
        } else {
            $str_tmp = substr($temp_var, 0, -1);
            $this->reduceOneAndCheck($str_tmp, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

`
These are the values that are used to test the solution:

```
Input: strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]
Output: "fl"
```

My code outputs just flight value, because as I came to understand when it comes to second iteration and check for common prefix between "*flower*" and "*flow*" and finding it is "*flow*" the **$temp_var** never gets assigned the "*flow*" value, instead it is empty and then the if in **longestCommonPrefix** method just assigns it to "*flight*" and that gets returned.
But I do not understand why it never gets assigned to "*flow*".

Many thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is at line:
  `$temp_var;`
just below
 `function longestCommonPrefix($strs) {`.
You are checking if `$temp_var` is equal to `""` or `null` but it has no initial value.

Solution: Change the said line with error to
`$temp_var = "";`

Comment: Hi! Changed the **$temp_var;** to **$temp_var = "";**
But the **$temp_var** still doesn't get assigned to correct value from **reduceOneAndCheck** method. On the second iteration the **$temp_var** is not assigned to the "_flow_" value from function return and therefore the final output is again "_flight_".